# Selenium: Ajax Testing

Tags: selenium, selenium2

Please brief me about the Ajax testing with selenium RC.
As in Ajax element does not reflect on the view-source, but using firebug we can see the changes in HTML source code.

There are two methods associated with it..

1. The method `waitForCondition` (java.lang.String script, java.lang.String timeout), to provide script we have to create a java script by own or it should be the same Ajax script/java script present on the web page.

Please correct me if i am wrong on below point:

2. The method `waitForElementPresent(Locator)`, we check the Element in the firebug and check the same in this method is self `waitForElementPresent(Locator)`.

Let me know  if anything else I am missing testing Ajax application.

Comment: Well if you answered your question and have got it right too :)

Comment: Hey @Tarun I still need the answer of the first point...:)  
Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already gave an example on a similar question which can be used to wait for Ajax and javascripts to finish.

Here it is:

```
selenium.waitForCondition(
        "selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0",
        timeout);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Only works if you are using jQuery, won't work for all AJAX sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hannibal and Ardesco for this great help. I got this form one article http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/?p=111 JQuery: “jQuery.active” Prototype: “Ajax.activeRequestCount” Dojo: “dojo.io.XMLHTTPTransport.inFlight.length” So if there is Ajax call we can use second option. Please correct me if I am missing something …. Thanks in Advance

Comment: True. But you can easily attune it to something else. :) Glad it helped smriti! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could you wait for condition like this -

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"element locator\")", "waitPeriod")
```

Hence you need to write the wait condition and here in I have used one of the Selenium API it self